# Force compile time error on sizeof operator

Tags: c++, sizeof

Sometimes we have a POD struct whose `sizeof` has a meaning for serialization purposes. From my PE parser, from example:

```
struct dos_header {
    unsigned short magic;
    unsigned short cblp;
    ...
    };
```

This structure is meant to be serialized from/to the PE image, so `sizeof` on it has a meaning on, say, `ifstream::read`.

This is invalid of course for non POD. The nt_header for example:

```
struct nt_header 
{
    std::uint32_t Signature;
    file_header FileHeader;
    std::variant<optional_header_32, optional_header_64> OptionalHeader;
}
```

Serializing with `sizeof` would be valid technically, but nonsense at runtime because the size of the structure is run-time dependent.

Is there a way to force the compiler to generate a compile time error when `sizeof` is used in such a class?

So, if I accidentally use `sizeof(nt_header)` somewhere, the compiler warns me.

Comment: Which compiler(s) do you use?

Comment: "*sizeof() it has a meaning for serialization purposes*" - how do you deal with padding/alignment?

Comment: @melpomene depending on the compiler, in Windows, #pragma pack(1) for such headers. However this is irrelevant here.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm MSVC, but the question is generic for any compiler.

Comment: From [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#overload-dot): _sizeof cannot be overloaded because built-in operations, such as incrementing a pointer into an array implicitly depends on it._ While _sizeof() it has a meaning for serialization purposes_ this is not the only purpose. Hence, there is no limitation on POD types intended. (May be, an extension tool based on clang could be used to detect this but I'm afraid false positives in `std` headers.)

Comment: Btw. serialization based on `sizeof` sounds like dumping binary data ignoring endianess. This is not portable (but I guess you are aware of it and ignore this to gain extra performance).

Comment: This is an XY problem, and you're barking up the wrong tree by trying to trigger an error on use of `sizeof`.   All you need to do is specialise your functions for reading or writing of objects based on whether they are a standard layout type.   This can be achieved using `std::is_standard_layout()`  (C++11 and later).   Standard layout types can be safely read using `ifstream::read()` on binary streams (assuming written by a program built with a compatible compiler) and other types cannot.

Comment: The operator is `sizeof`, not `sizeof()`. Programmers often add redundant parentheses, but they are still redundant. You should not use `struct` as a serialization protocol. There are half a dozen mor more ways it can go wrong.

Comment: @user207421 You have enough reputation to edit it, instead of posting a comment I guess.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I do, and I did, and I did it first, actually, but I don't accept 'instead'. The explanation has value, even if not to you personally

Comment: @user207421 — in `sizeof(type)` the parentheses are required. In `sizeof expression` parentheses are not required, although the expression can, of course, be wrapped in parentheses. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof).

Answer (score 0):

There’s no getting around the fact that using even `nt_header` for `memcpy` is fine so long as the alternatives are trivially copyable.  If that’s not the serialization mechanism you want to use for such objects… don’t?  It’s easy to provide a template that handles all your (de)serialization and is specialized to sometimes read less data (and, here, to compute the `variant`’s index from some other contextual information).